# Verify the alias in ant.properties is correct

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

Good morning

I'm trying to build an Android application on release mode using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.1

After I create my myreleasekey.keystore using  android tools
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

I set data in ant.properties

```
   key.store=C:\\Users\\myreleasekey.keystore
   key.alias=MoayadMyro
   key.store.password=password
   key.alias.password=password
```

I got error :

```
Error : BLD00213 : Signing key MoayadMyro not found. Verify the alias in   ant.properties is correct.

cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and no matter the permutations of keystore alias I tried, I kept getting the same error in visual studio for Apache Cordova.

To resolve I simply repeated the generation process.

1. Generate a new key store using keytool:

   ```
   C:\myChosenDir> keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore mykeystorename.keystore -storepass mykeystorepass -validity 10000 -keysize 2048
   ```
2. Enter the information requested as part of the keygen:

   When requested to enter the password for `<selfsigned>` reenter the password above. Hitting return suggests it uses the same but this is what I did before and it didn't work. [This was the only thing I did different]
3. Add the keystore to the project:

   I placed the keystore in the same folder as the `ant.properties` file
4. Update the ant properties file:

   ```
   key.store=mykeystorename.keystore
   key.alias=selfsigned
   key.store.password=mykeystorepass
   key.alias.password=mykeystorepass
   ```

[NB: preserve the line breaks can't get them to play correctly in markdown]

I know this a bit of a turn it off and turn it on again answer but it worked for me. Best of luck.